# delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11 error in M1 vscode

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gcc, apple-m1

I have a problem with delegating constructors in M1 vscode.

```
// Rectangle.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Rectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle() : Rectangle(1, 1) {}

Rectangle::Rectangle(int len) : Rectangle(len, len) {}

Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

double Rectangle::getArea() {
    return width * height;
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Rectangle.h"

int main() {
    Rectangle rect1;
    Rectangle rect2(13);
    Rectangle rect3(5, 8);

    cout << "rect1: " << rect1.getArea() << endl;
    cout << "rect2: " << rect2.getArea() << endl;
    cout << "rect2: " << rect3.getArea() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
//Rectangle.h
class Rectangle {
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(int len);
    Rectangle(int, int);
    double getArea();
};
```

```
(base) -@MacBook-Air-of-- - % g++ Rectangle.cpp main.cpp -o rectangle2.out
Rectangle.cpp:6:26: error: delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11
Rectangle::Rectangle() : Rectangle(1, 1) {}
                         ^~~~~~~~~
Rectangle.cpp:8:33: error: delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11
Rectangle::Rectangle(int len) : Rectangle(len, len) {}
                                ^~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

These are my source codes and my version is C++17 and I'm using code-runner. When I build one code, it works but When I separate codes, it doesn't.
I want to know that I could delegating constructors with no other options.
Thank you

Comment: *"are permitted only in C++11"* / *"my version is C++17"*. It seems you don't activate C++17 (for compiler or "intelisense" IDE)... Show your command line.

Comment: What errors do you get? How do you build the program? Please copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build-log into your question. If you use the standard code-runner plugin, include the command. Otherwise please show us your `tasks.json` file.

Comment: @Jarod42
`240318Rectangle % g++ Rectangle.cpp main.cpp -o rectangle2.out
Rectangle.cpp:6:26: error: delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11
Rectangle::Rectangle() : Rectangle(1, 1) {}
                         ^~~~~~~~~
Rectangle.cpp:8:33: error: delegating constructors are permitted only in C++11
Rectangle::Rectangle(int len) : Rectangle(len, len) {}`
This is my command line

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
I build my program to terminal `g++ Rectangle.cpp main.cpp -o rectangle2.out` like this. and I set the code-runner plugin in Code-runner:Executor Map for build but I forgot what I did

Comment: @7ib: show the command line directly in the question, and missing `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Apple Clang defaults to **C++98** standard.

Comment: @Jarod42 
```"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"``` is that correct?

Comment: @7ib VScode will have a lot of these issues. I would recommend using the terminal from the start instead of an IDE, vscode(editor) etc.

Comment: @prapin What should I do then?

Comment: Just ensure you are passing `-std=c++17` command line option to the compiler (which is missing based on error message)

Comment: @prapin I can understand everything. Appreciate it!